# suppressing horizontal lines on the last group record

Tags: crystal-reports

My report currently looks like this

```
Group Header Item
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item
                      --------------------------------------------   <--horizontal line
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item
                      --------------------------------------------
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item
                      -------------------------------------------- <-- SUPPRESS
 -----------------------------------------------------------------    <-- Horizontal Line in group footer
Group Header Item
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item
                      --------------------------------------------
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item
                      -------------------------------------------- <-- SUPPRESS
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to suppress the last horizontal line for the last item on each group so it doesn't have 2 horizontal lines in a row.

Answer (score 0):

In your design view change your horizontal lines from bottom of the text to top of the text so your report will look like

```
Group Header Item
                      --------------------------------------------
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item
                      --------------------------------------------   <--horizontal line
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item
                      --------------------------------------------
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item                          
 -----------------------------------------------------------------    <-- Horizontal Line in group footer
Group Header Item
                      --------------------------------------------
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item
                      --------------------------------------------
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item                          
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Other solution which will have output like below is to put your horizontal line in separate detail section and suppress it if it's last detail of group.

Then your output should look like

```
Group Header Item
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item
                      --------------------------------------------   <--horizontal line
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item
                      --------------------------------------------
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item                          
 -----------------------------------------------------------------    <-- Horizontal Line in group footer
Group Header Item
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item
                      --------------------------------------------
                      Detail Item     Detail Item      Detail Item                          
 -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

First solution is kidna simplier, second one needs formula for suppressing your `detail b`, `detail_a` contains data.

Hope it helps